# Is there anything that generally screws up running powershell base64 encoded scripts from a batch file?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, base64

Is there any reason why base64 encoding the code below and then running it from a batch file might prevent a shortcut to the batch file from running it?

```
%SystemRoot%\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -windowStyle hidden -EncodedCommand "<encoded-stuff>"
```

---

```
function profilesReviewedAddedRm() {
    tipATapAClickAClackA "Micros / BevEx profiles Reviewed, Add, Deleted.";
}

function tipATapAClickAClackA($tm) {
    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
    $wshell.SendKeys("%{TAB}");
    Start-Sleep -m 5000;
    $wshell.SendKeys($tm);
}

profilesReviewedAddedRm
```

The `$wshell.SendKeys("%{TAB}");` seems to just lose focus on the previous window.  I have another script that runs exactly the same way with different text passed in, and it gives me no trouble at all.

Using gvim to type things up if that matters.

Comment: Note, when I paste it directly into the powershell window it works fine.  But not when I paste the encoded powershell command however.

Comment: Does it work when you save the code to a `*.ps1` file and invoke it with `-File`?

Comment: Running from PowerShell ISE I am able to encode the command and execute it. I am also able to encode the command into a variable, write out the encoded string and run that separately in a normal PowerShell window.

Comment: Is the account you are running the batch script the same as you are encoding the command on?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician As far as I know, I generated it from a script in gvim that sets the gvim shell as the path to powershell and sets the shellcmdflags equal to the powershell arguments; it's then read back into vim from the command where I put it in the bash shell script.  https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20289/why-does-vim-call-powershell-surrounded-by-two-single-quotes

Comment: I've also tried decoding the string in powershell and it comes back as something the powershell can't display...I was wondering if it maybe had something to do with the encoding, before it is base64 encoded...I read it directly from the file where I coded it.  I also tried adding CRLF but that didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need to run encoded commands in the first place? Other than making it look like you're running malware and making life difficult for your co-workers, I mean.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers The latter I guess, but I don’t think they’re using it, it’s pretty specific to my own job.  I also wanted to check it with md5’s hashes the scripts, and raise an alarm if it changes.  At this job I’m not worried about it, but it’d be a nice skill to have if the situation changes somewhere else.  Besides, people can decode it.

Comment: How are you encoding it? The method I've used is `$Encoded = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($textstring))`.